# Is is acceptable to declare a private class as an alias?

Tags: java

In [my answer from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413606/using-directive-in-java/2413618#2413618) I called the following piece of code "a hack":

```
final class MyMap extends HashMap<SomeSuperLongIdentifier, OtherSuperLongIdentifier> {}
// declared MyMap as an alias for readability purposes only

MyMap a = new MyMap();
a.put("key", "val");
```

Giving it another thought, this does not seem like a bad idea at all, but I might be missing something. Are there any potholes I missed out on? Is this an acceptable (possibly creative) way for declaring aliases in Java?

Comment: Added the `final` modifier per the recommendations...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drawback would be that you won't be able to directly use any methods that return a correctly typed  `Map`, because they will never return a `MyMap`. Even if they could return a `Map<SomeSuperLongIdentifier, OtherSuperLongIdentifier>`.

For example you wouldn't be able to use the `filter()` methods in [`Maps`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) (provided by [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)). They would *accept* a `MyMap` instance as input, but they would *return* only a `Map<SomeSuperLongIdentifier, OtherSuperLongIdentifier>`.

This problem can be somewhat reduced, by writing your `MyMap` to delegate to another `Map` implementation. Then you could pass the return value of such a method into the constructor and still have a `MyMap` (without copying, even). The default constructor could just set the delegate to a new `HashMap` instance, so the default usage would stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think it surely a convenient way to declare type synonyms. Some languages have direct support for that (in Delphi (pascal), for example, you can do that like that:

```
type MyMap =  HashMap<SomeSuperLongIdentifier, OtherSuperLongIdentifier>;
```

Since Java does not, I think you can use inheritance for that. You need to document, that this declaration is just a synonym and noone should add meethods to this class. Note also, that this consumes a little memory for VMT storage.

Comment: To make sure that no one can add methods, just declare it `final`

Comment: @Aaron Digulla.  That only applies to subclasses.  Someone could come along later and add methods to `MyMap` and the `final` would not stop it.

Comment: Such a type synonym could be useful, but it's not possible in Java. A subclass is not a synonym.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: but it functions almost like it is, doesn't it?

Comment: unfortunatley not (depending on your definition of "almost"). A subclass is a subtype. That means that it can be used wherever the original type is expected. But the problem is that the opposite is not true (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

I would object to the name `MyMap`: Since you create an alias, make it document its purpose by giving it a useful name. Other than that, I like it.

Comment: `MyMap` is just an example name, of course in real-life code this should be a meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would not do this, and would flag it in a review, but this is a matter of opinion.

Google Collections helps mitigate this problem, by letting you declare:

```
Map<SomeSuperLongIdentifier, OtherSuperLongIdentifier> a = Maps.newHashMap();
```

I'd look for ways to refactor code to not have to declare so many instances of this Map, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

As long as developers using your code have IDEs and are able to quickly jump to the class definition and read the comments for its purpose (which are in place, no?), I can see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Additionally the aliasing problems are not that bad because the OP asked about "private" classes so the "alias" is not leaking.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it an 'alias'. It isn't. It can't be used interchangeably with the type it is supposed to be aliasing. So if that's the intention, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think that inheritance is a very big gun compared to the problem at hand. At the very least I would have made this "alias class" **final**, with a big fat comment describing the reason for its existence.

Comment: You also have to make a decision regarding the constructors you choose to expose.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two contradictory aspects here.

1. On a modelling point of view, your declaration is **right**, because it emphasizes the encapsulation your class provides.
2. On a coding point of view, your declaration may be considered as **wrong** because you add a class only as a modelling support, with absolutely no added feature.

However, I find your approach quite right (although I never though about it before), since it provides a much appreciated (well, to me, at least) compilable model : classes from your model are perfectly reflected in your code, making your specifications executable, what is very cool.

All this brings me to say it's definitely a great idea, provided you support it with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it a hack. Personally, I've created an alias for the purpose of declaring generic type parameters which cannot be changed and creating some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You also couldn't use this map in serialization if sending to another jvm which does not have your MyMap class.