# Java imports. Does it support import as aliasing?

Tags: java, import, alias

I have two distinct classes in my project called Calendar, from different packages.

Does Java have an import as syntax similar to Python?

i.e.: Something like this:

```
import package1.Calendar as p1.Calendar;
import package2.Calendar as p2.Calendar;
```

So, down an the new statement later I can just use the shorthand:

```
p1.Calendar c1 = new p1.Calendar();
```

rather than the full blown alternative:

```
package1.Calendar c1 = new package1.Calendar();
```

The package names I have are far more verbose than this...

Comment: Nope, there is no such thing. Sorry.

Comment: @HadiJ Obviously you have never actually tried what you suggest. You need the fully qualified class name in all four places. And your `.c1/.c2` syntax doesn't make much sense.

Comment: See also related question [“using” directive in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413606/using-directive-in-java)

Comment: Ok thanks. Tried searching and couldn't come up with correct search term to find that duplicate. (Sorry).

Comment: Thanks @user85421